# How to set Deployment Type using ECS First Run Wizard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

The AWS ECS First Run Wizard provides no option for choosing the 'Deployment type' of the ECS Service:
[image: First Run Wizard]

Whereas the ECS Service creation screen does:
[image: ECS Service]

Why does the First Run Wizard not allow for setting the same properties as the regular ECS creation screen does?  There's also no way to edit an ECS Service created via the First Run Wizard to change the Deployment  Type.

**How do I set the Deployment type of an ECS Service created via the First Run Wizard?**

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to setup Blue/Green deployment type for ECS. As Blue/Green deployment, there should be one environment (**Blue**) should exist before deploying another environment called **Green**. As it's your first project or first ECS services, there is no prior environment thus we cannot choose Blue/Green deployment in deployment type.

Comment: When creating a new service there is an option to make the Deployment Type ECS Blue Green right from the get-go.  But this option is missing in the wizard.  I guess the wizard just isn't full featured.